# CSS with white spaces

Tags: html, css

I'm currently trying to follow a tutorial to make an image gallry a-la-Apple but for now, I got a little problem that I can't understand the reason.

Here's the JSFiddle: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SA3d4/2/).

If you check correctly, you should see a white space on top of the second and third `li` item of the submenu in the slider. The first one doesn't have it.

There's the wanted result: [Tutorialzine](http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2009/11/beautiful-apple-gallery-slideshow/demo.html)

If someone can find the reason, it would be appreciated!

***Note: I'm using Twitter Bootstrap!***

Comment: I cant see any space, any specific browser?

Comment: Put all styling on the A-tag using display:block. Do not style the LI tag except for floats/positioning.

Comment: @Diodeus Post it as answer. IT WORKED! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Rule #1 for list-based menus**: Put all styling on the A-tag using display:block. Do not style the LI tag except for floats/positioning.

See my tutorial: http://preview.moveable.com/jm/ilovelists/